# BizTalk mapping RECADV D96A

Tags: biztalk

I need to convert the CSV file to EDIFACT RECADV D96A.

The input:

```
REC;A;ABC;120769;4502902610;0196466358;ABC;;202003051329;OB:505+DP:8718
RECD;1;110000;45;;  
RECD;1;120000;50;;  
RECD;1;130000;100;; 
RECD;2;200000;21;;  
RECD;2;210000;12;;
```

And the output should be:

```
LIN+1++1:EN'
GIN+BJ+110000:45'
GIN+BJ+120000:50'
GIN+BJ+130000:100'

LIN+2++2:EN'
GIN+BJ+200000:21'
GIN+BJ+210000:12'
```

This is what I managed to do until now:(take only first GIN for each line)

```
LIN+1++1:EN'
GIN+BJ+110000:45'

LIN+2++2:EN'
GIN+BJ+200000:21'
```

How can I do to take the number for each distinct line?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Usually when you can't do it using the mapper surface you need to write XSLT to do it.   Can you edit your question with sample schema and map?  That way it is easier for someone to reproduce the issue and come up with a solution